# Drupal 8 Rules and Media

Tags: 8, rules, media

I want to publish Media associated with content when the content is published.

Is that possible with rules?

If so, what are the conditions I need to set?

The conditions I have set are:

> 1. Node is published - data selector: node
> 2. entity has field - data selector: node, value: field_my_media_field

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens   Yeah I've seen that page. I know the module is still in alpha for D8. I was just thinking it might be possible in its current state. I'm not familiar enough with Rules to know how to build complicated configurations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is that possible with rules?

I'm [a bit](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3a39516%20%5brules%5d) familiar with the (amazing!) [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module. But to my knowledge the current answer to this question is ***No***, ***Non***, ***Neen***, ***Nein***.

#### More info

- Refer to [#d8rules status update November 2017](http://d8rules.org/news/d8rules-status-update) to get a better understanding of the current status of Rules for D8. Here are some (scary) quotes from it:

  > - ... Fago can’t dedicate time required to develop the module further. What Rules is really missing at the moment is development capacity to help finish the last milestone.
  > - ... Even if we got more funding today, fago the current principal maintainer of the Rules module wouldn’t have enough capacity to do the work himself.
- Start [here](https://drupal.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3616/39516) if you wonder how to contribute.

---

<sup>One never realizes what ***has been*** done, only what ***remains to be*** done ...</sup>